# How to effectively search on a delimited string in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle 11g table setup as:

```
CODE   VERSION   STRING_DATA 
AAA    1         aaa|bbb|EARTH|ddd|eee
AAA    1         aaa|bbb|MARS|ddd|eee
AAA    2         aaa|b22|EARTH|d22|eee
BBB    1         aaa|b22|EARTH|d22|eee
```

Now the STRING_DATA is broken down as:

1. col1
2. col2
3. location
4. col4
5. col5

How could I write a query similar to my psuedo-code?

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE CODE = 'AAA' AND VERION = 1 AND LOCATION = 'EARTH
```

Comment: Effectively? Do not store delimited values. The you can create an index which will be a lot faster when searching for a single value. Read up on database normalization

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  I didn't design this mess, I'm left to deal with it.

Comment: Well, sometimes re-designing is the better alternative.

Comment: Would be wonderful if a production system wasn't already tied into this.

Comment: Is the number of delimited fields in STRING_DATA always 5?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It's variable based on a parent record which contains a delimited string containing the column names.

Comment: Err.. then is location always the third token (even if the string may have more than five tokens)?

Comment: No.  I used that as a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Substr and Instr

```
   select * 
     from MY_Table
    where CODE = 'AAA' 
       AND VERION = 1 
       AND substr(string_data,instr(string_data,'|',1,2)+1, instr(string_data,'|',1,3)-instr(string_data,'|',1,2)-1)  = 'EARTH';
```

Comment: I like your answer over the `regexp_like` option because, although it is more complicated and harder to debug, it can be indexed.  It can also be encapsulated into a `VIRTUAL` column or a view.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
     my_table ( code, version, string_data ) as (
       select 'AAA', 1, 'aaa|bbb|EARTH|ddd|eee' from dual union all
       select 'AAA', 1, 'aaa|bbb|MARS|ddd|eee'  from dual union all
       select 'AAA', 2, 'aaa|b22|EARTH|d22|eee' from dual union all
       select 'BBB', 1, 'aaa|b22|EARTH|d22|eee' from dual
     )
select *
from my_table
where code = 'AAA' and version = 1 and regexp_like(string_data, '^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|EARTH\|')
;
COD    VERSION STRING_DATA
--- ---------- ---------------------
AAA          1 aaa|bbb|EARTH|ddd|eee
```

Comment: @Vercelli - sorry, I see it now, I forgot to anchor it to the beginning of the string. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @Vercelli - Ugh... I forgot how | works as OR in a regexp (thought that's only in parentheses, but it isn't). I'll fix that too - I need to escape it. Thanks for pointing these out!

Comment: no problem, anyway I think substr/instr combination should be less cpu intensive.

Comment: I agree, even with the extra comparison (I know that is true when you just need to extract the substring, but very likely true in this case as well).